# Tortoise SVN - Keyword for Date/Author of File Addition to Repo

Tags: svn, properties, tortoisesvn

Are there a set of SVN keywords which resolve the author and date properties on when a file was added (i.e. created) in SVN? $Date$ and $Author$ appear to only resolve to the user/date of the last commit.

I've trawled through the SVN docs, here and Google but can't find a definitive answer on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) is to always update to the last commit.

If you only want the original author and date then you could remove the keywords or `svn:keywords` property after the first substitution has occurred.

Comment: I suspected as much, thanks for clearing the air. Would have been nice not to have to do that though